# Stripe Apple Pay testing fro India

Tags: stripe-payments, applepay

How we could test Stripe Apple Pay integration from India? Tried by changing the region of the device to a location supported by Apple Pay like UAE, France, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a VPN to see if changing the IP allows you to test Apple Pay. I am not 100% certain that it would but worth a try.

Comment: Tried with VPN, but not able to see Apple Pay option.